# Flash getURL() wont' execute twice

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm maintaining a legacy Flash app that at one point calls ActionScript 2.0's function getURL()  (see https://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000564.html)

Existing code we have seems to be working fine for calling this once, passing the URL and "_blank" to put returned content into a new tab. We want to make changes now to populate two (or more) new tabs.

Surprisingly, the flash client won't seem to do it.

I tried code like:

```
getURL(myUrl1, "_blank");
getURL(myUrl2, "_blank");
```

in which case the content for myUrl2 will display (seems like the call for myUrl1 has just been lost?). If I flip the calls around:

```
getURL(myUrl2, "_blank");
getURL(myUrl1, "_blank");
```

I again get just one new tab, now displaying contents from myUrl1.

I figured this was some sort of timing issue, and so decided to set things up to use setTimeout() (https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/) function to introduce some delay.

If I setup the delayed callback, then call getURL() once right away, I get a new tab for the immediate call and a bit later (8 sec, 15 sec, 30 sec) the callback will in fact run but then it's like the getURL() call there is just ignored?!?

This isn't making any sense to me. :(

Can anyone explain why multiple getURL() calls fail? (Or offer a workaround or even just verify that they can replicate the issue?)

Have to ammend this:
(FYI: Looks like this is failing for Firefox 52.6, Chrome Version 64.0.3282.186 but actually works in IE 11.909. I thought at first this wasn't a browser issue, but seems like maybe it is? The .swf file is being generated from Adobe Flash Professional CS6 Version 12.0.0.481.)

Thanks! ;)

EDIT2:  A little more testing reveals that using the setTimeout() function with a delay as small as 2 seconds (maybe smaller will suffice) will actually cause both tabs to launch and display as expected under IE11. For the case of back-to-back getURL() calls, IE11 fails consistent with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Have you tried to give specific names to your target windows? Like getURL(myUrl1, "window1");
getURL(myUrl2, "window2");

Comment: Looking at the documentation for the getURL() function...   "You can enter the name of a specific window or select from the following reserved target names:"     Since we are trying to put this into a new window and not one that already exists, it seems like "_blank" is the correct value to use, right?

Comment: Theoretically - yes :) Practically - looks like the browser is messing it up with the same window name. Maybe upgrading to a newer flash player version might help?